# Assume some expression is false

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, mathematical-optimization, syntax, assumptions

I need to `Reduce` a complicated function and I want to exclude some conditions A and B. How do I assume that the expression A is `False` and the expression B is `False` and `Reduce` the function?

For instance, suppose f(x,y,z) is the function I want to use `Reduce` on, the expression A is `x> -2` and B is `z> -4`. How do I do:

`Assuming[{A (which is x> -2) is False, B (which is z > -4) is False},Reduce[{f(x,y,z)<0,x<0,y<0,z<0}]` ?

Comment: "A (which is x> -2) is False"  is equavalent to `x<=-2`.

Comment: Does `Assuming[{\[Not]A,\[Not]B},Reduce[f[x,y,z]<0,x<0,y<0,z<0]]` work?

Comment: You could use `Not[x>-2]`